# ORA-02298: cannot validate can not add foreign key to table

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

I have tried to add foreign keys to my patient table however it comes back
Error at line 2/16: ORA-02298: cannot validate (WKSP_119108025.FK_APPOINTMENT_ID) - parent keys not found

1. ALTER TABLE PATIENT
2. ADD CONSTRAINT fk_appointment_id
3. FOREIGN KEY (Appointment_ID)
4. REFERENCES Appointment (Appointment_ID);

this is the code i have placed in oracle apex

```
ALTER TABLE PATIENT
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_appointment_id
FOREIGN KEY (Appointment_ID)
REFERENCES Appointment (Appointment_ID);

ALTER TABLE Nurse_Notes
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_patient_notes
FOREIGN KEY (Patient_ID)
REFERENCES Patient (Patient_ID);
```

I have successfully added the foreign keys to other tables with the code :

```
ALTER TABLE Appointment
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_nurse_id
FOREIGN KEY (Nurse_ID)
REFERENCES Nurse (Nurse_ID);

ALTER TABLE Appointment
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_intervention_id
FOREIGN KEY (Intervention_ID)
REFERENCES Nurse_Intervention (Intervention_ID);
```

I would really appreciate your help with this.

thanks

Comment: This error is pretty on nose. Have you checked? Do you have appointment_id's in Patient that aren't in Appointment? Patient_Id's in Patient that aren't in Nurse_Notes?

Comment: You have one or more rows in `PATIENT` with a not null `APPOINTMENT_ID` and there is no row in `APPOINTMENT` with a matching `APPOINTMENT_ID`. Side bar: what do you do when the patient needs more than one appointment?

Answer (score 0):

> parent keys not found

Usually, it helps if you post exact error (code and message) your got, not your own interpretation.

I guess this is (simplified) current situation:

Master table (the one you're trying to reference):

```
SQL> create table appointment (appointment_id number);

Table created.
```

Detail table:

```
SQL> create table patient (appointment_id number);

Table created.
```

This is statement you ran:

```
SQL> ALTER TABLE PATIENT
  2  ADD CONSTRAINT fk_appointment_id
  3  FOREIGN KEY (Appointment_ID)
  4  REFERENCES Appointment (Appointment_ID);
REFERENCES Appointment (Appointment_ID)
                        *
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list
```

If I guessed it right, then error message says it all - master table (`appointment`) doesn't have unique nor primary key on `appointment_id` column. Let's add it:

```
SQL> alter table appointment add constraint pk_app primary key (appointment_id);

Table altered.
```

Does your statement works now? Yes, it does:

```
SQL> ALTER TABLE PATIENT
  2  ADD CONSTRAINT fk_appointment_id
  3  FOREIGN KEY (Appointment_ID)
  4  REFERENCES Appointment (Appointment_ID);

Table altered.

SQL>
```

---

Therefore, make sure that unique/primary key exists in table you're referencing.

As of statements that successfully did their job: it just means that these master tables already have unique/primary keys.

Comment: it is unfortunately a primary key in Appointment , i have double checked the tables there

Comment: CREATE TABLE Patient (
  Patient_ID INT,
  PatientFirstName VARCHAR2(50),
  PatientLastName VARCHAR2(50),
  PatientDOB DATE,
  PatientContact VARCHAR2(20),
  PatientAddress VARCHAR2(255),
  PatientGP VARCHAR2(50),
  PatientAlert VARCHAR2(255),
  Appointment_ID INT,
  PRIMARY KEY (Patient_ID)
);

Comment: CREATE TABLE Appointment (
  Appointment_ID INT,
  AppointmentDate DATE,
  AppointmentTime TIMESTAMP,
  AppointmentLocation VARCHAR2(255),
  Nurse_ID INT,
  Intervention_ID INT,
  PRIMARY KEY (Appointment_ID)
);